# Can we extend a class in playground on Xcode using Swift?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

The following code runs perfectly if it is in a standalone command line app:

```
extension Int {
    func sayHello() {
    println("Hello, I'm \(self)")
    }
}

1.sayHello() 
2.sayHello()
```

However, in playground, it won't run, and the error is "(2 times)".  Can we not extend a class in playground or how do we do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few corrections:

- "(2 times)" is not an error. It means your code was executed two times.
- `Int` is a struct (value type), not a class

You can click the eye icon to see the output:

[image]

Comment: interesting that if I have 2 statements instead: `println("Hello, I'm 1");
println("Hello, I'm 2")` then the results would show line by line... so I suppose it is: the `println` results won't show line by line if it is more than 2 lines if it is not the top level? (because if I define a function `hm()` to print something out and call it once, it would show, but call it twice, it also shows as `(2 times)`

Comment: Yes, that's how the main playground works. You can also try View -> Assistant Editor -> Assistant Editors on Bottom to see a more traditional console output.